# Sendemail command not found in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, sendmail

So I am trying to use sendmail in cygwin because on the server I cannot use other options like mutt because they aren't supported. I have downloaded the sendmail package during the cygwin setup, but when I try to run my code it says sendmail command not found.

This is my code I am trying to run in cygwin:

```
uuencode /somefilepathtoattachment | echo -e "to:  blahblah@email.com\ncc: blahblah@email.com\n\nAttached is a zip folder containing the reports for the snapshots" | sendmail -t -f someemail@email.com -s "Daily Snapshot Reports"
```

From some googling I tried to figure out the problem but I am stumped.
When I ran "whereis sendmail" I got this:

```
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail /usr/libexec/sendmail.exe /usr/share/sendmail /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/sendmail.dll
```

When I ran "which sendmail" I got this:

```
which: no sendmail in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Oracle/product/12.1.0/client_2:/cygdrive/c/Oracle/product/12.1.0/client_2/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/jdk11.0.11_9/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin:/cygdrive/c/HIS13/SysWOW64:/cygdrive/c/HIS13/system:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Sennheiser/SoftphoneSDK:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Webex/Plugins:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WinMerge:/cygdrive/c/php:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Windows Performance Toolkit:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/385959/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Users/385959/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39:/cygdrive/c/Users/385959/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Users/385959/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/385959/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin)
```

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: Sendmail is in `/usr/sbin` but that directory is not in your `$PATH`.  Try using an full path when executing sendmail.

Comment: Sendmail is working with the full path thanks

Comment: @doneal24 : This does not explain why `whereis` could locate it. `whereis` searches `PATH` and `MANPATH`, and since the directories returned don't look like containing man-pages, I would conclude that they were found in the PATH.

Comment: @user1934428 `whereis` looks both in the `$PATH` and in standard system locations. That is why it found `/usr/sbin/sendmail` even though it was not in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in a answer so that it will not be deleted and will be of use to future questions.

Sendmail is in `/usr/sbin` but that directory is not in your `PATH`. Try using an full path when executing sendmail.